# CCNet Take Installation from Multiple svn

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am going to automate our setup creation activity. For these I need to get 3 items from 3 different svns
a. application binaries from https://productvss:8443/svn/Connect200/branches/Release_5.0.0.0
b. logger binaries from https://productvss:8443/svn/Logger/branches/Release_2.4.7
c. License binaries from https://productvss:8443/svn/licensing/branches/Release_2.4

What is the best way for getting the files in CCNet? source code block or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are triggering the builds with something other than listening for changes on these repositories I would use Nant's exec task with the SVN command line tool to get the files.

```
<exec program="svn.exe">
<arg line="co https://productvss:8443/svn/Connect200/branches/Release_5.0.0.0 <local_wc_directory>"/>
</exec>
```

same idea for the other two repositories...

Answer (score 0):

Or you can **create a small SVN project with only externals** to your different projects path.
So When CC.NET do a checkout, it will get all the structure from different SVN path/Repo.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html